# Grails url redirection problems

Tags: grails, redirect

I have a Grails 2.0 webapp and when I try to go to an url, for example 
http://localhost:8080/${myapp}/controller/action it always redirects to http://localhost:8080/controller/action without the name of my webapp.
This is my UrlMappings.groovy

```
class UrlMappings {
static mappings = {
  "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
      constraints {
         // apply constraints here
      }
  }

  "/"(controller:"/admin")
  "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

}

And this is my application.properties

```
#Grails Metadata file
#Thu Feb 09 12:22:14 CET 2012
app.grails.version=2.0.0
app.name=appname
app.servlet.version=2.4
app.version=0.1
plugins.hibernate=2.0.0
plugins.tomcat=2.0.0
```

any suggestions why it redirects to the wrong url?

thanks for your time

Comment: Did you set `grails.app.context="/appname"` in your `Config.groovy`?

Comment: thanks for your response, I'll try it on monday, I'm not at the office

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved. In Config.groovy my server url was wrong

`grails.serverURL="http://localhost:8080"`

I had to use

`grails.serverURL="http://localhost:8080/appname"`

thanks

Comment: This answer helped me another way. We were not using this settings previously in Config.groovy. Somebody checked in recently this line and my local grails application was re-directing to this particular 8080 URL even though I ran it on a different port other than 8080.